# Symfony2 Doctrine2 UniqueEntity validation specifying a value

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I already use UniqueEntity in fashion like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="benefit_group_category")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "project"}, ignoreNull=false, message="Duplicated group category for this project")
 */
```

So I already know how to use it.

What I need to do in another context is the following:

```
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"entityId", "status"}, message="There is already a Quality Review Pending for this entity")
```

But I need to specify that for the same `entityId` I cannot have a duplicate if `status == 1`, but if `status == 0` it should pass the validation.

Basically, for example, I can have any number of records with `entityId = 37` and `status = 0`, but only one with `status = 1`.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** Please find here the updated version of it, for double checking. In my original question I forgot to mention another parameter (entityName) but it does not change the essence of it.

**Repository class**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * QualityReviewRequestRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class QualityReviewRequestRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
/**
 * @param array $criteria
 * @return array
 */
public function getByEntityIdAndEntityNameAndStatusCriteria(array $criteria)
{
    // Todo remove this first return, it's done on purpose to force the system to throw an error, but it doesn't.
            return $this->createQueryBuilder('e') 
            ->andWhere('e.entityId = :entityId')
            ->setParameter('entityId', $criteria['entityId'])
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;

    if (QualityReviewRequest::STATUS_NEW == $criteria['status']) {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->andWhere('e.entityId = :entityId')
            ->setParameter('entityId', $criteria['entityId'])
            ->andWhere('e.entityName = :entityName')
            ->setParameter('entityName', $criteria['entityName'])
            ->andWhere('e.status = :status')
            ->setParameter('status', $criteria['status'])
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }

    return [];
}
}
```

**Main class:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * QualityReviewRequest
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="quality_review_requests")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\QualityReviewRequestRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"entityId","entityName","status"}, repositoryMethod="getByEntityIdAndEntityNameAndStatusCriteria", message="There is already a Quality Review Pending for this entity")
 */
class QualityReviewRequest
{
    const STATUS_NEW = 0;
    const STATUS_DONE = 1;

    use TimestampableEntity;

    // removed useless stuff

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entityName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $entityName;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entityId", type="integer")
     */
    private $entityId;

    // More stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add [repositoryMethod](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#repositorymethod) option to UniqueEntity constraint annotation.

```
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"entityId", "status"}, repositoryMethod="getEntityByIdAndStatusCriteria", message="There is already a Quality Review Pending for this entity")
```

And implement repository method to find entities by defined criteria.

```
/**
 * @param array $criteria
 * @return array
 */
public function getEntityByIdAndStatusCriteria(array $criteria)
{
    if (1 == $criteria['status']) {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->andWhere('e.entityId = :entityId')
            ->setParameter('entityId', $criteria['entityId'])
            ->andWhere('e.status = :status')
            ->setParameter('status', $criteria['status'])
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }

    return [];
}
```

Comment: Your solution looked indeed very promising, but I must be making some mistake, as the method never gets called. I checked the syntax several times. I even changed the method name using one that is not present on the repo (on purpose), and it does not give me any error. It simply ignores me and adds the record on DB :/

Comment: It works well for me. Please make sure, that your repository class is defined in your @ORM\Entity annotation. (@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\EntityRepository")) And your cache has been cleared after you've defined repositoryMethod. Also please try to perform "die();" in your repository method code to make sure it called properly. Do you have any validation groups in your entity?

Comment: please see my updated question. No validation groups. The method does not even get called (I wrote some stuff that must fail, like $criteria['inexistentCriteria] and it never gets there to throw an error). The repo class has been generated automatically, so shouldn't be an issue. I'm sure it's a silly thing. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I cleared the cache the hard way (deleting the directory)

Comment: Do you have any other validation constraints in this entity, which is works fine? Could you please post your form type class and part of controller's code which process the form?

Comment: Ok, I got it, that's because in this specific case we don't pass the entity to the form, we create it inside the isValid(). So, given that we cannot have form validation, can we call the validation manually after having created the entity, before persisting? We won't have a form error but we can still notify the user.

Comment: You can use Validator service without form to validate your entity, here is an example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#using-the-validator-service